# a problem on complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $w\neq 1$ and $w^{13} = 1$.

If $a = w+ w^3 + w^4 + w^{-4} + w^{-3} + w^{-1}$ and $b = w^2+ w^5 + w^6 + w^{-6} + w^{-5} + w^{-2}$, then the quadratic equation whose roots are $a$ and $b$ is ... ?

I got $w=\cos(\frac{2\pi}{13})+i\sin(\frac{2\pi}{13})$
And then I found $a$ and $b$ in trigonometric form. But when I multiplied them to get the product of roots it gets very difficult. How to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please typeset your equations with [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for better presentation.

Comment: These are Gaussian periods: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_period

Comment: Also, you are more likely to get views if you actually title your "question" properly. Something like "Solving quadratic roots of complex numbers" is much better then your current title

Comment: "And then I found a and b in trigonometric form. But when I multiplied them to get the product of roots it gets very difficult."  If you found a and b in trig form how can multiplying them together be difficult?

Comment: Ditto what K Split X said.  Many people will simply ignore questions that are titled something like "question about subject-tag".  I know I certainly am not going to read the problem statement.  Keep the tags in the tags section, and put your question in the title, or some adequate abbreviation of it.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: the equation you want is $(z-a)(z-b)=0$. Expand the product and you get $$z^2-(a+b)z+ab=0$$
Step 2: Use $w^{13}=1$, so $w^{-1}=w^{13}w^{-1}=w^{12}$ similarly, for all negative powers $$w^{-n}=w^{13-n}$$
Step 3: $$a+b=w+w^3+w^4+w^9+w^{10}+w^{12}+w^2+w^5+w^6+w^7+w^8+w^{11}=\\=\frac{w^{13}-1}{w-1}-1=-1$$
Step 4: To find $ab$, go to the trigonometric representation, and notice $$w^n+w^{-n}=2\cos\frac{2\pi n}{13}$$

**Edit:** After some manipulations, and using $w^{n+13}=w^n$, I've got $$ab=3(w+w^2+w^3+w^4+w^5+w^6+w^7+w^8+w^9+w^{10}+w^{11}+w^{12})=\\-3+3(1+w+w^2+w^3+w^4+w^5+w^6+w^7+w^8+w^9+w^{10}+w^{11}+w^{12})=-3$$

Comment: I got to this point. I can not solve the trigonometric part.

Comment: I went back to $w$ and wrote explicitly the product

Comment: I think Step 3 should give $a+b=-1$. Note that $\frac{w^{13}-1}{w-1}=1+w+w^2+\dots+w^{12} = a+b+1$.

Comment: Fixed that. I forgot to add and subtract one. I've just added.

Comment: Andrei, it is not entirely necessary to relate $a$ and $b.$ See page 16 in https://books.google.com/books?id=wt7lgfeYqMQC&pg=PR1&lpg=PR1&dq=reuschle++tafeln+complexer+primzahlen&source=bl&ots=VGZFPrfUBn&sig=MlQ667PqXaQ9rAvLWkG3_F1rwsk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIwtSvm9TQAhUJ-2MKHXJIA_kQ6AEIODAE#v=onepage&q=reuschle%20%20tafeln%20complexer%20primzahlen&f=false  The method is due to Gauss, modern discussion (but just a few examples) in   http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/cox_galois_Gaussian_periods.pdf

Answer (score 2):

$$ a^2 + a = \frac{ w^{16} + 2w^{15} + w^{14} + 2w^{13} + 3w^{12} + 3w^{11} + 3w^{10} + 3w^9 + 6w^8 + 3w^7 + 3w^6 + 3w^5 + 3w^4 + 2w^3 + w^2 + 2w + 1}{w^8} $$

This is not impressive without
$$ w^{16} + 2w^{15} + w^{14} + 2w^{13} = w^3+2w^2+w+2. $$ Therefore

$$ a^2 + a = \frac{  3w^{12} + 3w^{11} + 3w^{10} + 3w^9 + 6w^8 + 3w^7 + 3w^6 + 3w^5 + 3w^4 + 3w^3 + 3w^2 + 3w + 3}{w^8} $$

The one coefficient out of line is $6 w^8 / w^8,$ so we need to subtract 3
$$ a^2 + a -3 = \frac{  3w^{12} + 3w^{11} + 3w^{10} + 3w^9 + 3w^8 + 3w^7 + 3w^6 + 3w^5 + 3w^4 + 3w^3 + 3w^2 + 3w + 3}{w^8} $$

$$ a^2 + a -3 = \frac{ 3 \left( w^{12} + w^{11} + w^{10} + w^9 + w^8 + w^7 + w^6 + w^5 + w^4 + w^3 + w^2 + w + 1 \right)}{w^8} $$

and
$$  a^2 + a - 3 = 0  $$

Comment: Elegant solution, but it might be at a higher level than what the question wanted. It would have probably had different tags.